# "Get us late" vs "Make us late"

Tags: word-usage

> You're going to get us late.

> You're going to make us late.

Does the first sentence work?

( "We got late" doesn't work, but "she got me wet" works, so I was wondering if "she got us late", "you're going to get us late" work)

Comment: The expression is **to make us late**. People would understand **she got us late** but it is awkward and not idiomatic. So, no it doesn't work.

Comment: I would understand "You're going to get us late" to mean that an act was pushed back in the lineup, and would be appearing later than initially billed.

Answer (score 1):

As @Ronald Sole said, no it doesn't work. There's no particular reason why it doesn't work - it simply doesn't.

But that *gets us** to core of the difficulty with using 'get/got/gotten': it is quite unpredictable in how it can be used, is sometimes viewed as informal or even 'wrong' by pedantic grammarians, and how and when it can be used differs substantially between American and British English.

While, as [this page and podcast make clear](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/is-got-proper-english), there is nothing inherently wrong or ungrammatical about the word 'get' and 'got', it is an area that an novice English speaker might be well advised to avoid, especially in written English.

The advice I received as a child, while certainly not to be interpreted as a rule of English language or grammar, is still useful: you can always replace 'get/got/gotten' with another verb that avoids any danger of accidental informality, or, as in this case, using 'get' where it would sound unnatural.

[*See what I did there?]