# I have got it open/I have got it opened/I have gotten it open?

Tags: idiomatic-language

If I want something that can be translated to "I've managed to open/get into the safe", which of the sentences could I use:

1. ***I've got the safe open. Are you coming?***
2. ***I've got the safe opened. Are you coming?***
3. ***I've gotten the safe open. Are you coming?***

?

Is there a more natural way to say this?

Comment: It is difficult for me to open the safe; hence I've got it opened. It means, someone else opened it for me.

Answer (score 2):

['Got' is tricky](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=got) and there are [other answers](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/257729/get-us-late-vs-make-us-late/257743#257743) which deal with why it can be unpredictable, and varies substantially between American English and British English in both how it is used, and when it is considered 'polite' or 'formal'.

All three of your examples *can* be used and would not be considered unnatural, although number 2 is a bit of an edge case. Number 3 would only ever be said by an American speaker.

But, as is almost always the case, you can say the same thing with fewer words and avoid 'got' altogether:

> **I've opened the safe. Are you coming?**